# getchar() function doesn't gets called only the first time during a while loop

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that lets the user play the game craps.

Two dices are rolled, if their sum is 7 or 11 the user wins, if it's 2, 3 or 12 the user loses, while for any other number, the user keeps rolling dices until he either hits the value of the first roll again, winning, or hits a 7, losing. Then the user gets asked if he wants to play again.

My algorithm works just fine but I'm still encountering a very simple problem right at the very end. When the user gets asked if he want to keep playing for the first time, the program stops correctly and waits for the user to input either 'y' or 'n', running the code again correctly if the answer is affirmative or just exiting the program if it isn't. If the user inputs y though, the second match plays correctly but once "Play again?" gets printed out the program doesn't wait for user input anymore and just exits the program. I don't really get why this happens, as the getchar() function is still there and it should always be executed...

Here's my code anyways:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int roll_dice(void);
BOOL play_game(void);

int main(){
  BOOL game;
  char check;
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

  do{
    game = play_game();

    if(game == TRUE){
      printf("\nYou win!\n");
    }
    else{
      printf("\nYou lose!\n");
    }

    printf("\nPlay again?: ");
    check = getchar();

  }while(tolower(check) == 'y');

  return 0;
}

int roll_dice(void){

  int x, y;

  x = (rand() % 6) + 1;
  y = (rand() % 6) + 1;

  return x + y;
}

BOOL play_game(void){

  int first_roll, x = 0;

  first_roll = roll_dice();
  printf("\nYou rolled: %d", first_roll);

  if(first_roll == 7 || first_roll == 11){
    return TRUE;
  }
  else if(first_roll == 2 || first_roll == 3 || first_roll == 12){
    return FALSE;
  }
  else{
    while(x != 7 && x != first_roll){
      x = roll_dice();
      printf("\nYou rolled: %d", x);
    }
    return x == 7 ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }

}
```

Comment: `getchar()` is leaving the newline in the buffer. You need to consume it. [Clarification needed regarding getchar() and newline](//stackoverflow.com/q/12544068)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ohh I see, thanks. So I declared a new variable `char trash` and put the instruction `trash = getchar()` right after the `check = getchar()`. This works, but isn't there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Assuming no chance of EOF: `check = getchar(); for(;getchar() != '\n';) /*void*/;`

Comment: **C** already defines a `bool` data type, as well as `true` and `false`, in the `stdbool.h` header file.  i would suggest using it instead of creating your own.

Comment: @Tau I'm using C89, my compiler doesn't support stdbool.h

Comment: ah, apologies.  i'm used to using C99 (or really the most up-to-date version, i can't recall which one it is).